# Multicast in enterprise network

Tags: security, multicast

Once I have heard from a professional that multicast is forbidden (or not suggested or not allowed) in enterprise networks from 2014. (He referenced to a standard or recommendation document or something else. I don't remember that reference)
I have searched this on the internet, but nothing found which states something about multicat allowance in enterprise networks.

Does anybody know something about multicast in enterprise networks?

Comment: `Does anybody know something about multicast in enterprise networks?` Yes. But we probably won't be able to write an introductory article about multicast here, I'm afraid. Please be more specific in your question, and be sure to ask about "Layer 4 and lower" topics. That might turn out to be difficult, because with multicast, the cross-dependencies between application and  transport/network layers are are even stronger and more complex than with unicast UDP/TCP.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi, I mean Layer 4 and lower layers.
I'm an admin of an enterprise network and authorities want to enable multicasting on the network. (new service needs multicasting). I configured basics for multicasting (IGMP, PIM, and IGMP snooping)on the network and it works correctly. (I tested multicasting by VLC media player).
By the way, I'm not sure that enabling multicast on our network is a good choice. I sense that it has more cons than pros and my hearing from that professional approves my sense. 
I feel I missed some security stuff in the configurations.
That's all!

Comment: So what specifically is your question?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking multicast (in general or partially) is a network design and security decision that each enterprise needs to make for their own. There is no standard that prohibits multicast generally.

Multicast can greatly increase the efficiency of your network when there are flows than can be mapped. It is quite possible to have a high security level even when multicast is used. Of course, when used without network restrictions multicast can be used to bypass other filters. As with other techniques, if you allow multicast you need to do it in a controlled fashion.

With IPv6 multicast support is *mandatory*, (somewhat) replacing IPv4's broadcast, so generally banning multicast is not pratical.